# Search and replace strings that are not substrings of other strings

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, replace

I have a list of replacements like so:

```
search_and -> replace
big_boy -> bb
little_boy -> lb
good_dog -> gd
...
```

I need to make replacements for the above, but at the same time avoid matching strings that are longer like these:

```
big_boys
good_little_boy
```

I tried this:

```
sed -i -r "s/$(\W){search}(\W)/$\1{replacement}\2/g"
```

But the above does not work when the string ("good_dog" in this case) occurs at the end of a line like so:

```
Mary had a 'little_boy', good_little_boy, $big_boy, big_boys and good_dog

Mary had a 'lb', good_little_boy, $bb, big_boys and good_dog
```

And I doubt the above would work when the string occurs at the start of the line too. Is there a good way to do the search and replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNU sed (which bare `-i` suggests you are), there is a ["word boundary" escape `\b`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes):

```
sed -i "s/\b$SEARCH\b/$REPLACE/g"
```

`\b` matches exactly on a word boundary: the character to one side is a "word" character, and the character to the other is not. It is a zero-width match, so you don't need to use capturing subgroups to keep the value with `\1` and `\2`. There is also `\B`, which is exactly the opposite.

---

If you're not using GNU sed, you can use alternation with the start and end of line in your capturing subpatterns: `(\W|^)`. That will match either a non-word character or the start of a line, and `(\W|$)` will match either a non-word character or the end of a line. In that case you still use `\1` and `\2` as you were. Some non-GNU `sed`s do support `\b` anyway, at least in an extended mode, so it's worth giving that a try regardless.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: @Michael Homer: What `sed` version support `\b` except `GNU sed`?

Comment: I was thinking mostly of Busybox's `sed`, I think, but of course that's GNU-based anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you want more portable, you can use `\<` and `\>`:

```
sed -i "s/\<$SEARCH\>/$REPLACE/g" file
```

`\<` and `\>` work in gsed, ssed, sed15, sed16, sedmod.

`\b` and `\B` work in gsed only.

In `Mac OSX`, you must use this syntax:

```
sed -i '' -e "/[[:<:]]$SEARCH[[:>:]]/$REPLACE/g" file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use perl, which should support `\b` on all platforms. Assuming your list of replacements is in the format you show (separated by `->`), you could do:

```
perl -F"->" -ane 'chomp;$rep{$F[0]}=${$F[1]}; 
                  END{open(A,"file"); 
                    while(<A>){
                        s/\b$_\b/$rep{$_}/g for keys(%rep); 
                        print
                    }
                  }' replacements
```

#### Explanation

- The `-a` makes perl run like awk, automatically splitting fields into the array `@F` so `$F[0]` is the 1st field, `$F[1]` the second etc. The `-F` sets the input field separator, just like `-F` in awk. The `-n` means "read the input file, line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line".
- `chomp` : removes newlines (`\n`) from the end of the line.
- `$rep{$F[0]}=${$F[1]};` : this populates the hash `%rep` making the pattern to be replaced (the first field, `$F[0]`) the key and the replacement (`$F[1]`) the value.
  *`END{}` : this is executed after the input file (`replacements`) has been read.
- `open(A,"file")` : open the file `file` for reading with filehandle `A`.
- `while (<A>)` : read the file line by line.
- `s/// for keys(%rep)` : this will iterate through all the keys of the `%rep` hash, saving each key as the special variable `$_`. The `s///` is the substitution operator and is making the same substitution as explained in [Michael's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144132/22222).

---

You could also read through the file and use `sed` as shown in the other answers:

```
$ sed 's/->/\t/' replacements | 
    while IFS=$'\t' read from to; do sed -i "s/\b$from\b/$to/g" file; done
```