# sed file comparison

Tags: sed, regular-expression

In OSX, the following command removes patterns and affects whole words:

```
sed -e "$(sed 's:.*:s/&//g:' /path/to/wordsToRemove.txt)” /path/to/sourceFile.txt > outFile.txt
```

`wordsToRemove.txt` contains:

```
it
for
```

`sourceFile.txt` contains:

```
it was green forever for candy
```

`outFile.txt` contains:

```
was green ever candy
```

The word "forever" is matched and has been changed to "ever" although I wanted to match the word "for" on its own, not as part of "forever".

Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: I've edited your post based on what I think is your problem. Please feel free to rollback the changes/edit your post again if what I wrote is not what you meant.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144131/search-and-replace-strings-that-are-not-substrings-of-other-strings  maybe especially cuonglm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can match *word boundaries* in sed by using the special markers `\<`, `\>` in your regexp.

For example:

```
 $sed -e 's/\<for\>//g' < sourceFile.txt 
 it was green forever  candy
```

This regexp only matches "for" as an entire word, not as part of forever.

You can therefore change your original oneliner as

```
sed -e "$(sed 's:.*:s/\\<&\\>//g:' /path/to/wordsToRemove.txt)” /path/to/sourceFile.txt > outFile.txt
```

Note the escaping of `\<` and `\>`.

Comment: It works on OSX, but still is not POSIX, I believe.

Comment: OSX's sed is supposed to be POSIX-compliant, as far as I know.